# ReactJS: Why shouldn't I mutate nested state?

Tags: reactjs

I've read the ReactJS documentation about *setState*. Specifically, this line:

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

But in my code, I do things like this:

```
var x = this.state.x;
x.y.z.push("foo"); // z is a list
this.setState({x:x});
```

This code seems to work and update state correctly. But according to the documentation, I'm breaking the rules. What's the problem with this approach? Are there performance issues? Race conditions? Will I be scolded by the Facebook dev team? Ideally, I'd like to avoid the immutability helpers and all the other craziness and keep things simple.

Comment: Use this.forceUpdate() instead. Or use React.addons.update to achieve the same results.

Comment: Things might appear to work now. However, that's likely to give way to hard to debug problems later on. The immutability rule really is a (strong) encouragement to never give a component access to more information than it needs. If your component needs to know about x.y.z, but not x or x.y, have z in your state `var z = this.state.z` and `this.setState({z: z.concat(['foo'])})` (initialize z through props). If the external world needs to know about changes in z, dispatch a change event that will trigger the update of x in the parent component or trigger an action that will update the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you miss out on the callbacks associated with `this.setState` and they claim that you may overwrite data by just assigning straight to the object.

Also, often in OOP (I don't know how many stars JS gets...) you'll use getter and setter methods instead of directly manipulating the object. In this example via `this.state.prop1 = "xyz";`

I've never had react overwrite my directly set state properties. The temptation to code it this way may be write to state without re-rendering. But if you're doing that you may think about not putting those in state anyways.

If re-rendering performance is an issues checkout https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: This is correct ^^ IT should be noted that if you manipulate state directly, then you have to keep track of what data was already in state, which can become tedious. A patch pattern is much easier to maintain, which is what the setState function enforces.

Answer (score 6):

By manipulating state directly, you are circumventing React's state management, which really works against the React paradigm.  The most significant benefit of React's `setState` is that it immediately triggers a re-render, which merges your DOM changes from the shadow DOM into the document DOM.  So, you capture all the state changes you need in some handler, then build up the state changes you want in a literal object, then pass that to `setState`.  This is not quite what your example above does.

So while the code sample you provided *technically* breaks this rule, since you are calling `setState` directly after mutating through a reference to a state object property, your changes are immediately being funneled through React's state management.  So, everything will work as you expect. The idea is that you don't want to get in the habit of making many changes to state in this way, it's better to capture your intended state in a new literal object or array, then set it to the state once (i.e., with no previous mutations of state) through a call to `setState`, which will trigger a single re-render.

EDIT: To more definitively answer your question, I would add that the real concern is that a dev would directly manipulate state in many different places or methods, *without* calling `setState`, and then at some later point or other code, call `setState` and then wonder why their render isn't producing the results they expected.  Since `setState` does an object *merge* between the known, managed state, and the literal object passed as an argument to `setState`, it's possible the results would not be what you would expect if you had previously manipulated state directly.

Comment: Do you have a source/link for this information? I'm interested in learning about how calling setState triggers a re-render.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#how-state-works

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify, I only call setState after making all of my changes to the state object.
The question about how the results could not be what I expect -- that's what I'm trying to delve into. How can the results go wrong?

Comment: The idea is that you could mutate state, and then make a `setState` call that doesn't include your previous mutations, and essentially override them, then confuse yourself as to why you aren't getting the expected result.  However, as we discussed, in your usage pattern above this isn't likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that shouldComponentUpdate will not work correctly.